# Find all distinct combinations of letters in a string

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, combinatorics

I've been preparing for interviews and picking up modern C++. A recent prep question I did was to find all combinations (or distinct subsets) of letters from a string.  E.g. `'AA2'-> {'A', '2', 'A2', 'AA2'}`.  Note that the order doesn't matter.  I would like feedback both on the approach and on use of C++ style/best practices.  My attempt is:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

std::unordered_set<std::string> getPermutations(std::string str){
    std::unordered_set<std::string> ret;
    if (str.length() <= 1){
        ret.insert(str);
    } else {
        char removedLetter = '\0';
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if (removedLetter == str[i]){ //Already found all subsets missing this character
                continue;
            }
            removedLetter = str[i];
            std::string subString = str.substr(0, i) + str.substr(i+1, std::string::npos);
            std::unordered_set<std::string> shorter = getPermutations(subString);
            for(auto shortPerm : shorter){
                ret.insert(shortPerm);
                auto ind = shortPerm.begin();
                for(; ind < shortPerm.end(); ind++){ //Find where to insert letter so that ordering is preserved for eliminating duplicates
                    if(*ind > removedLetter){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                shortPerm.insert(ind, removedLetter);
                ret.insert(shortPerm);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); //Sort string so that method works.
    for(const auto &p :  getPermutations(str)){
        std::cout << p << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In the example, the empty combination is omitted. Is this on pourpose?

Comment: Yes, no empty combination, and input is at least one character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Minor remarks**

- Since the sortedness of the input is a precondition of `getPermutations`, I would either do this step in the function itself, or at least add a check for this condition.
- Passing string by reference instead of by value: I recommend passing `const std::string &` instead of `std::string`. In this way, the string does not get copied to the stack. This matters especially, if the string is very long.

**Alternative**

While the recursive approach is elegant and easily understandable, it might be less convenient for very long inputs. I suggest another solution, based on the idea, that if you want all permutations, then each character can either be part, or not be part of a permutation. This gives us 2^N possible permutations, where N is the length of the input. So, you can just generate this number (2^N), and then iterate from 0 to 2^N-1, and calculate the corresponding perm. for each number. So, if the number is represented as binary digits, then 1 means that the character at the corresponding position should be part of the permutation, 0 that it should not. (If you do not need the empty perm., just start the iteration from 1, instead of 0.)

With your example, 'AA2', this would work as follows: N=3, so iterate from 0 to 7 (=2^3 - 1). 0 corresponds to the empty set. 1 = 001b, so '2' is part of the permutation. 2 = 010b, so only (the second) 'A' is part of the permutation. 3 = 011b, so the perm. is A2, etc.

Remarks:

- This approach would yield two identical 'A2' perms., but you can avoid that by storing the return value in a set, as you are currently doing it (unless you do want both).
- With this solution, it is not needed to sort the input.
- Other representations are possible as well, e.g a vector of booleans, instead of a number (especially convenient very large inputs).

Comment: Thanks!  Good point about using `const`; I hadn't thought about an iterative solution b/c this question was in the recursion section, but that's a nice approach!